# Unable to use C# ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, configurationmanager

I have the following code:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace test
{
  public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
  {
    public  static ReadConnectionStrings()
    {                        
      ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections =
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
```

However, it doesn’t recognise ConfigurationManager.   I took this code directly from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

So I’m clearly missing something, but can’t identify what.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Do you have a reference to `System.Configuration`?  It's not added to .NET projects by default.

Comment: What if this is shared project?

Answer (score 18):

I was having the same issue.

It took me a little while to figure out that adding the reference is not adding the using.  I had to right-click the project and select Add Reference, then pick System.Configuration in the .NET tab.

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the actual `project` you're working in has a reference to `System.Configuration`. I was working in a data access project, not the presentation layer's project. So I was getting a bit confused because I had thought I had a reference, but in reality the `data project` was missing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the assembly refernce then add to project not sure if others had this problem